# Error in Executing Jobs on Slave In Jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, master-slave

I have Master Slave configuration under Jenkins.I wanted to run a job on the slave system under Jenkins I order to do that I have copied the required scripts and files But I have been getting the following error

Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on `MySlave` in workspace `C:\Users\prathamesh.n\workspace\MasterSlave`

`FATAL: Cannot find executable from the chosen Ant installation "apache-ant-1.9.4"
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure`

Archiving artifacts
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level C:\Users\sudharshan.r\workspace\Ant\exec\reports\Test 1 to C:\Users\sudharshan.r.jenkins\jobs\Project 11\htmlreports\HTML_Report
ERROR: Specified HTML directory 'C:\Users\sudharshan.r\workspace\Ant\exec\reports\Test 1' does not exist.
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: C:/Users/sudharshan.r/workspace/Ant/exec/reports/Test 1/testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...

[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: `FAILURE`

need help on executing ant on slave

Comment: Do you have ant installed on your slave? If yes what's the path?

Comment: I have ant installed on my slave.Path Is C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin

Answer (score 0):

Click on Jenkins - > Manage Jenkins -> configure system -> Under Ant, define your installer and then in your job select that ant configuration.

Comment: I have already defined my installer and then selected it in my job configuration

Comment: how did you define it? Do you have execute permission on ant?

Answer (score 0):

Whats your configuration in your build? *Default* or let's assume *my 1.9*.

Now in "configure jenkins": Add a specific ant e.g. with name *my 1.9*.

- easiest way is **automatic installation** and installation from Apache
- if you don't want to do this: uncheck automatic installation and give your path were you installed ant in the field: ANT_HOME